# What is the guaranteed way to get not null Context in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I saw many examples for how to get the Context in BaseFragment like this:

```
protected lateinit var ctx: Context

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    ctx = context!!
}
```

And then we can use the context instance in our other fragments that extend BaseFragment. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30641537/6367262), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24256683/6367262), [three (it's offered to get Context from onViewCreated())](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53580994/6367262) and so on. **It looks like workaround.**

I also had some cases when "fragment detached from Activity" exceptions occurred while using getActivity() or getContext() in Fragment.

So, what's the true way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't guarantee context to be 100% non null, this is why it is marked as nullable (?), so the 'workaround' you mentioned actually will cause exception in case the activity detached.
To avoid it don't mark `ctx:Context as lateinit var` make it nullable `protected var ctx:Context? = null` and check it state each time you want use it.

Comment: It will be null even if I won't assign the null value in onDetach()? I mean that it's referenced to activities Context and will be not stored in my BaseFragment? And if activity detaches, my lateinit var will overwrite the value to null?

Comment: Yes, context is just a reference to Activity in this case and if activity die the context will die too no matter where it was stored.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer!